# SynchronizationContext is null in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a library which relies on capturing the SynchronizationContext in order to post callbacks back to the UI thread.

A user was having a weird condition where the callbacks were being posted to the ThreadPool instead. After investigating a bit, I came up with the following two test cases:

#### 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Test test;

    public Form1()
    {
        test = new Test();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("It's null! :(");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Test test = new Test();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("It's null! :(");
        }
    }
}
```

The 1st test runs fine, but the 2nd one throws an exception. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example `new Test()` runs (almost) as the very first code in the program. Probably, your `Main` function calls `new Form1()` which immediately calls `new Test()`.

A `SynchronizationContext` must be set before it is present (obviously). There is nothing magic in the runtime that guesses that your app will use WinForms. Using WinForms is a dynamic runtime decision. WinForms will set its `SynchronizationContext` when you use WinForms (I forgot the exact trigger points).

In the first example the `base` constructor (`new Form()`) runs first which apparently installs the `SynchronizationContext`.

When you run code before any WinForms code runs no `SynchronizationContext` will/can be present.

There is nothing sane that your library can do about this. You could add an assert or manually set the WinForms sync context (there is a API for that) but that is hardly the business of a library. Libraries are not supposed to mess with global state. (Except if your library is clearly meant for WinForms-only use).

Comment: For reference, `SynchronizationContext` is set in the constructor of the first control created - [`Control()` in ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,535). Basically the constructor for `Test` in test 2 is called before the constuctor for the `Form1`. Therefore at this point no control has been created, so the `SynchronizationContext` has not been set.